# How to obfuscate an apk with Proguard through Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I added `proguard.config=proguard.cfg`to my default.properties file and have a proguard.cfg file in my project root. If I now use Export as Android Application from within Eclipse I get the following Errors:

```
[2011-01-27 11:11:37 - Application] Warning: class [classes/com/package.Class.class] unexpectedly contains class [com/package.Class]
[2011-01-27 11:11:37 - Application] Warning: class [classes/com/package.Class2.class] unexpectedly contains class [com/package.Class2]
[2011-01-27 11:11:37 - Application] Note: there were 145 duplicate class definitions.
[2011-01-27 11:11:37 - Application] Warning: there were 146 classes in incorrectly named files.
[2011-01-27 11:11:37 - Application]          You should make sure all file names correspond to their class names.
[2011-01-27 11:11:37 - Application]          The directory hierarchies must correspond to the package hierarchies.
[2011-01-27 11:11:37 - Application]          If you don't mind the mentioned classes not being written out,
[2011-01-27 11:11:37 - Application]          you could try your luck using the '-ignorewarnings' option.
[2011-01-27 11:11:37 - Application] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2011-01-27 11:11:37 - Application]     at proguard.InputReader.execute(InputReader.java:133)
[2011-01-27 11:11:37 - Application]     at proguard.ProGuard.readInput(ProGuard.java:195)
[2011-01-27 11:11:37 - Application]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:78)
[2011-01-27 11:11:37 - Application]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:499)
```

It seems that somehow my classes are saved in a classes subfolder but Proguard uses this classes subfolder as a package. Therefore the definition of the classes can not be understood by Proguard.

Is this a problem with my SDK Setup? Or are there errors in my Proguard Configuration causing this problem?

Comment: You'll need to post your proguard.cfg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that is convenient I just updated to the the new ddms Eclipse pluging Version: Android DDMS 9.0.0.v201101191456-93220 and updated my SDK to the new Version that includes Honeycomb and the problem seems to be gone.

Comment: Now that you've exported it, can you actually run the apk on a device other than an emulator? I was thinking of upgrading to 3.0 but the release notes say that apks will only run on the emulator.

Comment: I do not compile for honeycomb with the sdk and therefore my apps surely run on normal devices.

Comment: I've only been able to integrate the use of proguard and ant via command line; if it's possible to export a proguard'ed android app and skip the command line then I'm quite excited...

Answer (score 1):

I changed the proguard.cfg slightly from whatever was working for me last May and now it works:

from

-injars bin

to

```
-injars bin/classes
```

I also had to clean-up a bit--removing Junit (which wasn't used in this project) and the compatibility library (which I probably could have ignored away, but chose to ditch altogether instead).

Answer (score 0):

### Steps to get obfusticated apk:

1) Download latest proguard from "http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/". Current latest version is proguard4.7

2) Replace "bin" and "lib" folder of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\proguard" with latest downloaded proguard folders.

3) Check SDK location in eclipse for blank spaces in it and for that go to window > Preferences > Android. If there is blank space then replace it with:

```
    c:\Progra~2\android\android-sdk (for windows 64-bit)
    c:\Progra~1\android\android-sdk (for windows 32-bit)
```

4) Check that proguard.cfg file is in your project's root folder and add "proguard.config=proguard.cfg" in project.properties file of android project.

5) Now export your project to get obfusticated apk.

I hope that it will help.

Comment: In step 4) Check that proguard.cfg file is in your project's root folder. Can you explain, where exactly to place this file? And also, how to know whether the project is obfuscated correctly?

Comment: i couldn't find any proguard.cfg and i found proguard-project.txt

Comment: @Shrikant you can verify obfuscated apk by file size, and if you see these files(dump.txt, mapping.txt, seeds.txt, usage.txt) in progurad folder in your project explorer it means you can say that your apk is obfuscated.