# Proguard Parse Exception Error. How to solve it

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I am trying to export my application using Proguard 4.9 for the first time. But while exporting I am getting weird error in Console. Here it is -

```
[2013-06-11 14:59:42 - Project1] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-06-11 14:59:42 - Project1] proguard.ParseException: Expecting type and name instead of just '***' before '(' in line 193 of file 'D:\Project Works\Android\Project1\bin\proguard.txt',
[2013-06-11 14:59:42 - Project1]   included from argument number 4
[2013-06-11 14:59:42 - Project1]    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseMemberSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:889)
[2013-06-11 14:59:42 - Project1]    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:729)
[2013-06-11 14:59:42 - Project1]    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parseKeepClassSpecificationArguments(ConfigurationParser.java:516)
[2013-06-11 14:59:42 - Project1]    at proguard.ConfigurationParser.parse(ConfigurationParser.java:165)
[2013-06-11 14:59:42 - Project1]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:476)
```

Here is the bin\proguard.txt file of line 192 & 193, where the error is coming

```
# onClick res/layout/tmenu.xml #generated:77
-keepclassmembers class * { *** (...); }
```

In project.properties I am using

```
target=android-7
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

And I am Android SDK and eclipse's plugins are updated to latest. Any idea how to fix it???

**EDIT**
Here is the proguard.cfg in my project

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error is at

```
-keepclassmembers class * { *** (...); }
```

Replace with

```
-keepclassmembers class mypackage.** { *; }
```

---

And if you set this config for setters/ getters, you need to modify as

```
-keep class mybeans.** {
    void set*(***);
    void set*(int, ***);

    boolean is*(); 
    boolean is*(int);

    *** get*();
    *** get*(int);
}
```

Where : The '`***`' wildcard matches any type (primitive or non-primitive, array or non-array). The methods with the 'int' arguments matches properties that are lists.

Comment: It's in bin folder, how to modify?

Comment: I am saying about the actual file change. Not in the file which is in bin.

Comment: are you using external Proguard?

Comment: I am using proguard first time and using this link to use it : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815167/how-to-obfuscate-an-apk-with-proguard-through-eclipse

But the version mentioned over there and I am using is different. I am using 4.9

Comment: You are doing the wrong... you need not to replace the Proguard. Android SDK have its own ProGuard, so no need to download and use another... So revert back what you did. And then you will find a file `android.pro` which having more details of Android project settings.

Comment: And you will get `proguard-project.txt` file into your project, you have to write your all settings into that file.

Comment: requires 15 reputation, 2 more required. Once I get it I am definitely going to upvote it

Answer (score 20):

In my case I was receiving this error because of an empty onClick attribute in a layout file. So I removed `onClick=""`, and the error was gone

Comment: WTF... How did you even find that? Thanks!

Comment: Exactly this. The exception is so so understandable.

Comment: Tip: Check the log file generated, it will give you a line number that will tell you which xml file has this issue.

Comment: I love SO and you sir.

Answer (score 11):

In my case the error was due to an empty onClick attribute on a button in a layout file. So I removed `onClick=""`, and the error was gone.

TO find the the correct layout file that causing this error go to the corresponding file and find which layout file is causing this problem.
The file is rightly on the or one line above the line indicated in the error message like

```
In line 193 of file 'D:\Project Works\Android\Project1\bin\proguard.txt' or  in line 114 of file 'C:..app\build\intermediates\proguard-rules\debug\aapt_rules.txt' .
```

Go through the layout file and find the `onClick=""` in any view. Remove it.

Hopefully this will work.

Comment: even I have faced this issue.